# Using Langchain LLMs, define Falcon 7B model

Tags: python, langchain

I am trying to define [Falcon 7B model](https://huggingface.co/tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct) using `langchain.llms`. Now I know it supports [GPT4All](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/gpt4all) and [LlamaCpp](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/llamacpp)`, but could I also use it with the new Falcon model and define my llm by passing the same type of params as with the other models?

Example:
`llm = LlamaCpp(temperature=model_temperature, top_p=model_top_p, model_path=model_path, n_ctx=model_n_ctx, n_batch=model_n_batch, n_gpu_layers=model_n_gpu_layers, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=False)`

I tried passing the same params to Falcon as GPT4All and LlamaCpp but I am not sure if langchaim.llms support this model.